# Get data from URL with parameters Swift

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I need get data from an url.
Using postman, for example, if I try a get request with this my private `url = "http://127.0.0.1/MyWebService/api/fetch_image.php"` and add in params : 
id_key -> id_team 
in value -> 2 
the software returns this to me:

> {"image_team":[{"id":1,"img_path":"http://localhost/MyWebService/images/Schermata.png","id_team":2},{"id":2,"img_path":"http://localhost/MyWebService/images/Schermata.png","id_team":2},{"id":3,"img_path":"http://localhost/MyWebService/images/Schermata.png","id_team":2}]}

now in Swift I have written these classes:

```
class ClassJsonTeam: Codable {

private var teams: [JsonTeam]

init(teams: [JsonTeam]) {
    self.teams = teams
}

func getTeams()-> [JsonTeam]{
    return(self.teams);
}

func setTeams(teams:[JsonTeam]){
    self.teams = teams;
}

}

class JsonTeam: Codable {
private let id: Int
private var name: String
private var member: Int

init(id: Int, name: String, member: Int) {
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.member = member
}

func getId()->Int{
    return(self.id);
}

func setId(id:Int){
    self.member = id;
}

func getName()->String{
    return(self.name);
}

func setName(name:String){
    self.name = name;
}

func getMembers()->Int{
    return(self.member);
}

func setMembers(members:Int){
    self.member = members;
}    
}
```

The question is: how can I make the request and save the date in the class?

(I'm using Swift 4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but this is horrible *objective-c-ish* code.

You obviously want constants in your classes so **declare** constants, and in almost all cases you don't need classes at all

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    let teams: [Team]

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case teams = "image_team" }
}

struct Team: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let imagePath: URL
    let teamID: Int

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case id, imagePath = "img_path", teamID = "id_team" }
}
```

That's it. Nothing else. No weird public getters and private setters. No initializers when dealing with `(De)codable`. And if you would use *swiftier* keys you can omit the `CodingKeys` declarations completely. The key `imagePath` can be even decoded as `URL`.

And finally: No trailing semicolons!

To read the data use traditional `URLSession`

```
let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1/MyWebService/api/fetch_image.php")!
let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
    if let error = error { 
       print(error) 
       return 
    }
    do {
        let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data!)
        print(result)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
dataTask.resume()
```

To add parameters you have to append a `query` to the URL for example

```
http://127.0.0.1/MyWebService/api/fetch_image.php?id_team=2
```

but this depends on your backend.

Comment: Furthermore I would suggest that you unwrap the url and not use the bang operator. In addition, you can also remove the let dataTask and use .resume() at the end of the curly bracket.

Comment: @FloWy If the URL is a literal constant and you know it's valid there's nothing wrong with force unwrapping it. Omitting `let dataTask` is a matter of taste 

Comment: I totally agree, but in my opinion it is bad practice. If you are the only one in your team it is ok, but if you have a larger project with multiple teams it is better practice to unwrap the url.

Comment: @FloWy I strongly doubt that people working on larger projects in teams would ask such a question here on SO 

Comment: Everything is possible :D